# How to use Planet Lab tiles in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: leaflet, planet, tile-server, jupyter-notebook

I just want to use Planet tiles as a basemap for a Jupyter Notebook application, using ipyleaflet widget.

In my environment, I imported these packages:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, TileLayer
```

Now, I am trying to initialize a map and streaming Planet tiles using my API.

```
planet_tiles_url=("https://tiles{0}.planet.com/basemaps/v1/planet-tiles/global_monthly_2016_05_mosaic/gmap/{x}/{y}/{z}.png?api_key=abc123")
tile_layer=TileLayer(url=planet_tiles_url)

m = Map(
    default_tiles=tile_layer,
    center=center,
    zoom=14,
    scroll_wheel_zoom=True)

m.add_layer(tile_layer)
m.add_control(LayersControl())
m
```

No error pops up. But no Planet basemap is displayed and not even the layer controls. See image..

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that looks wrong is `tiles{0}`. Try just `tiles`. If that works, then try `tiles{s}` for a small performance improvement.

The other issue is the order of `x`, `y` and `z` in the tile URL. It should be `{z}/{x}/{y}`.

Here is working code:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, TileLayer
planet_tiles_url=("https://tiles.planet.com/basemaps/v1/planet-tiles/global_monthly_2018_10_mosaic/gmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?api_key=API_KEY")
tile_layer=TileLayer(url=planet_tiles_url)

m = Map(
    default_tiles=tile_layer,
    zoom=4,
    scroll_wheel_zoom=True)

m.add_layer(tile_layer)
m
```

[image]

Comment: It did not work, but now I have another problem, the map doesn't show up. Not even the OpenStreetMap tiles which are default in ipywidget. I fix that, and let you updated.

Comment: What version of ipyleaflet?

Comment: I have ipyleaflet 0.9.1

Comment: Thx for providing a working example. As soon as I understand why no map appears in my NB, I will let you know if this works for me.